# SDL2 either lost OpenGL context or functions not defined

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2, openglcontext

I am initiating the display, the renderer and the OGL context off of the display. None of these gives an error, following is how I create these elements.

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
{
    printf("SDL initialization failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

if ((display = SDL_CreateWindow("",
    50, 50, 600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL)) == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

if ((graphics = SDL_CreateRenderer(display, -1, 0)) == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not get renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

if ((*context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(display)) == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not get context: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
    printf("GLEW couldn't be initialized: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    return false;
}

scene = SceneManager();

return true;
```

Now, after these, methods like glClearColor or glClear work as intended, however, methods like glCreateProgram or glActiveTexture point to NULL and throw a runtime exception. If I don't include glew in the header, these functions aren't even identified.

Am I losing my OpenGL context somehow and end up with an error, or are these functions not defined in SDL and I have to use another library to link these functions?

Comment: This is perfectly normal. `glClearColor (...)` and `glClear (...)` are part of OpenGL 1.0. `glCreateProgram (...)` is part of GL 2.0 and `glActiveTexture (...)` is part of GL 1.3. You need GLEW to get those functions on a platform like Windows, that only provides OpenGL 1.1 and leaves anything newer than that up to the display driver to extend at runtime. I would suggest you do something to this effect: `const GLchar* version = glGetString (GL_VERSION), renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER);  printf ("%s %s\n", version, renderer);` and amend your question with that info.

Comment: You need to set your opengl version, using `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, versionNumber);` and `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, versionNumber);`

Comment: It says glGetString returns unsigned byte, so I used unsigned byte, but both those values returned NULL.

Comment: Could it be that he is testing `(*context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(display)) == NULL`, and that never evaluates to NULL?

Comment: Well, how can I lose a GL context between classes, I never destroy the one I create.

Comment: It was without the pointer before, the same result so I decided to try it that way, don't think it makes a difference. I was using the field with a pointer in that case as well, so comes down to the same thing. But just to be on the safe side, I've turned it back to its original form, still the same thing.

Comment: Please show exactly where you called `glGetString (...)` from. It sounds like you are doing this in a class, and you may be constructing an instance of your class *before* the context is even created.

Comment: I called it in the constructor of SceneManager, and as you can see it happens right after everything is created. Again to be on the safe side, I tried calling it before scenemanager, it didn't output anything. So it somehow gets destroyed in here somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description of `SceneManager`'s constructor in comments, your problem has to do with ***when*** the constructor is called.

> I called it in the constructor of SceneManager, and as you can see it happens right after everything is created. Again to be on the safe side, I tried calling it before scenemanager, it didn't output anything. So it somehow gets destroyed in here somewhere?

At the beginning of whatever scope `SceneManager scene` is declared, C++ implicitly constructs the object using the default constructor. Thus, `scene` is actually constructed ***long*** before you get around to making a copy assignment on this line: `scene = SceneManager ();`

You are not "losing your OpenGL context", you simply do not have one when the `scene`'s constructor is called for the very first time. This why you usually declare these things like `SceneManager* scene` and then defer instantiation of the object `scene` points to until much later using `new`. You can either do that, or stop doing this in the constructor. But you cannot do things the way you have them right now, or you will call GL functions before SDL even creates a context for them.

Comment: Thanks Andon for your help and effort. This was the problem. You saved me a ton of time.